# Limit of some series ( slightly unrigorous mathematics)

Tags: power-series

I was reading a proof of the central limit theorem, where some taylor expansions were involved. Eventually, I got that 
 $$\log M_x(t)=n\left[\left(\frac{t^2}{2n}+ \frac{t^3}{6n^{3/2}}+\dotsb\right)-1/2\left(\frac{t^2}{2n}+ \frac{t^3}{6n^{3/2}}+\dotsb \right)^2+\dotsb\right].$$
It follows without proof that  $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \log M_x(t)= t^2/2$, but I do not understand why this holds.
I guess this has something to do with the fact that we are working with 'exponentially-fast converging' power series. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Are $x$ and $n$ supposed to be the same here?

Comment: X stands for the random variable under which we compute the moment generating function. ( just ignore it. has really no connexion. my question is why we can take the first term and say this is the limit)

Comment: In that case, you can't really mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}$, can you?

Comment: @GregMartin   Yes You are right. That is  a typo. I am sorry for the confusion and thank you for your observation. I changed it

Comment: It is not clear what all of the integers in the denominators are.  What are they?

Comment: Ok, getting closer. Do you agree that, if one is allowed to take the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ term-by-term on the right-hand side, that the result follows? If so, are you asking why that is in fact allowed?

Comment: @GregMartin yes that is what I am asking. Does it have something to do with uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, probably something like the Dominated Convergence Theorem is involved. Hard to tell without knowing the exact series in question.